# OSX:convert psn to args

Tags: objective-c, macos, bash

OSX passes -psn_0_XXXXXXX instead of args to scripts that are run as apps.

I am looking for a way to convert convert psn to args, to be used like this:

```
cat /Applications/MYAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/MYAPP

#!/bin/bash

ARGS=$(psn2arg $*)
/opt/local/bin/MYAPP $ARGS
```

Comment: sooo, you are looking for some command line tool (or code to create a command line tool) named "`psn2arg`"?

Comment: given `psn2arg "-psn_0_XXXXXXX"`, what is your desired output?

Comment: name it anything you like so long as it converts psn to args :) the output would normally be the path of one or more files opened with the app but could be anything.